# Unable to reach virtual router running within Linux VM from another Linux VM (using EVE-NG)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I recently deployed the EVE-NG VM into GCP. In short this VM allows me to test routers and switches which are virtual. These virtual devices run within EVE-NG. I would like for some of these virtual devices to communicate with other VMs that I have setup in GCP. So far I have not had any success. I've read the following article on how to do this: https://openeye.blog/2020/04/21/deploying-eve-ng-on-google-cloud-platform-part-3/ but I am still not able to ping a router from my other Linux VM or vice versa. Do I need to create a 2nd VPC network or something? I've very new to GCP in general.

Comment: The first thing you need to check is if you are able to ping the external IP of the VM where EVE-NG is hosted. If that is good, there is nothing that needs to be done on the GCP configuration side since VM to VM already works. The main thing you will need to focus on is the configuration of EVE-NG and also the network setup of your VM. It is possible that you will need to use port forwarding, trace first where the connection times out or fail.

Comment: Thank you, Alex G. Do I need to create a separate VPC in GCP since I'm dealing with different subnets?

Comment: Not necessary to